# Azure loadbalancer for two vms which are listening on same port number 8005. How to route traffic from frontend IP of loadbalancer?

Tags: azure

I have a special requirment. I created azure loadbalancer which has frontend IP 65.x.x.x, and two azure vms, already configured loadbalancer rules. Two azure vms applicatios are listening on port 8005. So i want to route traffic from azure loadbalancer. If i hit 65.x.x.x:8005, it should route route traffic to healthy vm. SO how to create security rules to open port.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a special requirement, it's how load balancers work. You need to add an allow rule to any network security group that is applied to the VM's to allow traffic from "AzureLoadbalancer" to port 8005 pm the VMs. You also need to ensure any firewall you have on the VM its self allows that traffic inbound.